# What is the most direct way to push a site update to Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I've SSH into the server and into the Laravel folder. I updated one of the html footer files but the changes aren't reflected on the website. I feel like I probably need to recompile something.

I tried deleting and re-creating the `.env` file (I backed it up first).

I've tried running the following commands:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
```

The only way I can seem to update the site is by updating the main.min.js file, located at `/laravel/public/assets/js/main.min.js` which is a terrible way to update the site.

How do I force Laravel to recreate this file or recompile the site based on changes I made to html template files within the site?

What am I missing here? I don't have any Laravel experience and am trying to update this site for a client.

edit:
I think I need to clarify a bit more...

The site appears to be rendered from this file: `/public/assets/js/main.min.js`

Most of the site's homepage, for example, is located in this js file. But the file is minified and therefore unwieldy to edit directly.

I am assuming (and I could be completely wrong here) that the file is generated from the html files located in the Laravel folder. To support this notion, I have found html files in other directories that correspond to the html located in the main.min.js file.

My assumption is that the previous developer would update the html files and then run *something* to compile the site into javascript files. But maybe this has nothing to do with Laravel, per se, and more to do with some frontend framework?

Comment: OP are you using cPanel hosting?

Comment: Yes, it's a cPanel account on a WHM VPS we run.

Comment: why you dont add version to your css and js files ? like `example.js?v=12345` and the 12345 is just a variable in env file ?

Comment: Where exactly did you change stuff? Which file exactly? If you didn't change anything in Javascript, there shouldn't be a need to recompile it. Also, did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: I can directly change text in `/public/assets/js/main.min.js`and the changes will be reflected to the site. However, this isn't a good way to change things, as the file is minified so I won't be able to make any larger/significant changes. The file is obviously being compiled... somehow... from somewhere... And I initially assumed this had to do with Laravel, but I could be completely wrong about that....

Comment: It's probably being built using webpack. `npm run prod` or `yarn run prod` will rebuild all the sites assets.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cached views...

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: php artisan view:clear
Zend OPcache requires Zend Engine API version 220121212.
The Zend Engine API version 220131226 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Zend Technologies at http://www.zend.com/ for a later version of Zend OPcache.



                                                          
  [InvalidArgumentException]                              
  There are no commands defined in the "view" namespace.

Comment: Well now you have another question you can ask here on stackoverflow :)  I have never encountered an error like that.   But you can safely manually delete all the cache files in `/storage/framework/views`  Try that I guess.

Comment: Yeah I think I am sorta giving up on running the deployment script, as there are just too many variables to go wrong. Instead, I'm simply trying to force an update to Laravel and skip the rest.

I deleted the files in `/storage/framework/views` but the site is not updating. I think I need to somehow force the `/public/assets/js/main.min.js` to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel assets reside in

> resources/assets/js

of your root directory you can have look their

if your file `main.js` is build using `laravel mix` have a on `webpack.mix.js` which compiles all your files you can get idea from that. make sure to run

```
npm run prod
```

if you change any file

Hope this helps?